# Is it possible to get the intersection of sets using dask?

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have a big dataset (50 million rows) in which I need to do some row-wise computations like getting the intersection of two sets (each in a different column)

e.g.

```
col_1:{1587004, 1587005, 1587006, 1587007}
col_2:{1587004, 1587005}
col_1.intersection(col_2) = {1587004, 1587005}
```

This works fine for my dummy dataset (100 000) rows.
However, when I try the same with the actual one the memory runs out

My coding works using pandas
1:1 porting it to dask does not work
*NotImplementedError: Series getitem in only supported for other series objects with matching partition structure*

playing around with map_partitions so far did not work

working code:

```
df["intersection"] = [col_1.intersection(col_2) for col_1,col2 in zip(df.col_1,df.col_2)]
```

replacing pandas df with dask df runs in the non implemented error:

```
ddf["intersection"] = [col_1.intersection(col_2) for col_1,col2 in zip(df.col_1,df.col_2)]
```

using map_partions "works" but I do not get how I assign the result to my existing ddf

```
def intersect_sets(df, col_1, col_2):
    result = df[col_1].intersection(df[col_2])
    return result

newCol = ddf.map_partitions(lambda df : df.apply(lambda series: intersect_sets(series,"col_1","col_2"),axis=1),meta=str).compute()
```

just doing:

```
ddf['result'] = newCol
```

Leads to:
*ValueError: Not all divisions are known, can't align partitions. Please use `set_index` to set the index.*

**update:**
resetting the index removes the error however then the column containing the intersections does not any longer match the other two columns. It looks like the order got messed up...

```
ddf2 = ddf.reset_index().set_index('index')
ddf2 ['result'] = result
```

I would expect a dask dataframe with the following columns

```
col_1:{1587004, 1587005, 1587006, 1587007}
col_2:{1587004, 1587005}
col_3:{1587004, 1587005}
```

Not only a perfectly working solution is appreciated also just some insights on how map_partitions works would help me already a lot :)

**update:**
Thanks to M.Rocklin I figured it out. 
For the future me or others stumbling about this question:

```
ddf = ddf.assign(
       new_col = ddf.map_partitions(
           lambda df : df.apply(
                        lambda series:intersect_sets(
                                series,"col_1","col_2"),axis=1),meta=str)
 )
 df = ddf.compute()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a function that works on pandas dataframes:

```
def f(df: pandas.DataFrame) -> pandas.Series:
    return df.apply(...)
```

Then you can map this function across your partitions

```
df['new'] = df.map_partitions(f)
```

I think that your problem is that you've called a compute here needlessly, and so you're trying to push a pandas dataframe into a dask dataframe.

```
# Don't do this
new = df.map_partitions(f).compute() 
df['new'] = new  # tries to put a pandas dataframe into a dask dataframe
```

Comment: sorry for coming back to you so late...but I first had to make sure that it runs doing some pandas multiprocessing. Finally got time to play around with Dask again...
Thanks a lot for the clarification :) 
For others I finally ended up like this:
ddf = ddf.assign (new = ddf.map_partitions(f))